# React.js Onclick event on a dynamically generated button is not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am new to React.js and have gotten stuck on writing a fucntionality. I have a form in which i am trying to add a set of data a numerical value & a web address. Once a user clicks the add button, a row is dynamically generated within the form with the values displayed and option to either edit or delete the said value. The user can add as many of these rows as they want.

The code to generate these dynamic rows is below

```html
let orderStandardDetails = '<div id={standardInfo_'+orderStandardInformationChildNodesLength+'} class="standardInfo"><br /><input id="orderStandard_'+orderStandardInformationChildNodesLength+'" class="orderStandardInfo" type="text" value="ISO '+orderStandard.toString()+'" name="standardInfo" disabled/>' +
      '<input id={orderStandardUrl_'+orderStandardInformationChildNodesLength+'} type="text" class="orderStandardUrlInfo" value="'+orderStandardUrl+'" disabled/>' +
      '<button class="orderStandardEdit" id={orderStandardEdit_'+orderStandardInformationChildNodesLength+'} onClick={this.editOrderStandard}><img src="app/images/Edit.svg" /></button>' +
      '<button class="orderStandardDelete" id={orderStandardDelete_'+orderStandardInformationChildNodesLength+'} onClick={this.deleteOrderStandard()}><img src="app/images/Delete.svg" /></button>' +
      '<button class="orderStandardSave" id={orderStandardSave_'+orderStandardInformationChildNodesLength+'} onClick={this.saveOrderStandard()}><img src="app/images/Save.svg" /></button></div>';
```

Also, I am binding the function as follows inside the constructor

```html
this.editOrderStandard = this.editOrderStandard.bind(this);
  this.deleteOrderStandard = this.deleteOrderStandard.bind(this);
  this.saveOrderStandard = this.saveOrderStandard.bind(this);
```

The said function is defined as follows

```html
editOrderStandard(){
  alert("Edit");
}

deleteOrderStandard(){
  alert("Delete");
}

saveOrderStandard(){
  alert("Save");
}
```

**The issue is that none of the above three functions are firing on clicking teh button. Moreover, in the firefox console i cannot see any errors pertaining to onclick.**

Please help.

Comment: can you post your render method, where you are trying to render orderStandardDetails

Comment: It seems that `orderStandardDetails` is what you want to render, instead of string concatenation to build dom structure, you should do something like `let orderStandardDetails = (<div id={'standardInfo_' + orderStandardInformationChildNodesLength} class="standardInfo">...</div>)`

Comment: Remember: a _string_ that looks like JSX and may even be formatted as JSX in your code editor is not the same as JSX itself.

Comment: So, I am basically writing the below line to render the above document.getElementById('orderStandardInformation').innerHTML = orderStandardDetails;

Comment: You are  doing it the wrong way. You should not do dom manipulations, let react handle this

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin Is there a way to render it inJSX format rather than the string as it seems that is what is happening

Comment: @Dev How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

> First things first, you should avoid to do DOM manipulations and let react take care of it. As suggested to you in comments, you should use JSX. For more info: [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)
>
> You can create stateless components which you want to dynamically render and let the parent component take care of state changes.
>   Below sample is for reference.

```js
const OrderStandardDetails =(props) => {
  return ( 
    <div class = "standardInfo">
      <input class = "orderStandardInfo"
      type = "text"
      value = "ISO"
      name = "standardInfo"
      disabled / >
      <input type = "text"
      class = "orderStandardUrlInfo"
      value = ""
      disabled / >
      <button class = "orderStandardEdit"
      onClick = {props.onEdit}>Edit</button>
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onEdit = this.onEdit.bind(this)
  }

  onEdit() {
    alert("Edit");
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <OrderStandardDetails onEdit={this.onEdit} />
     </div>
    
  };
}
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using redux, check out [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/)'s [fieldArray](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/fieldarray.md/). I think the example provides functionality similar to what you are looking for.

[Redux Form - Field Arrays Example](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/fieldarrays/)